# Performance Testing through JMeter for BOBJ application

Tags: jmeter

I had a script running successfully, when I add the users >3 to my testplan I see an error for the URL launch requests

```html
<html><head><SCRIPT>location.replace ( 'VintelaErrorServlet?vint_cms=%40BI42UAT&vint_backURL=%2FInfoView%2Flogon.faces');</SCRIPT></head><body></body></html>
```

Still the script able to kickoff other requests (able to execute the BOBJ reports successfully)

How do I decode the above error?